# Same named system user accounts distinguished by password

Tags: windows, security, user-accounts, login, login-screen

Is there a specific OS or some setting on linux/windows that will allow having at least two same named accounts which will look as one until is user logged in? Imagine it as having one main account and one hidden, where the only way to log in the hidden one is using right password when logging into the main account. I know there is a [way](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-hide-specific-user-accounts-sign-screen-windows-10) to make win 10 account "invisible", but there is no way to log in this account from login screen.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do this. Never on Windows, and I just checked my Linux machine and not there either.

Two different users cannot have the same name and you cannot set up a duplicate account. That will not even let you get to the password entry.